# Trouble with stylus button of Samsung Note

Tags: android

I am working on a game in Galaxy note. I am using a layout that changes color on touch. I have done that in action up and action down.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                  mCell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gn_sudo_grille_selection);


            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mCell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grile);

            }

            return false;

        }
```

I have a problem. On action down, the color will be changed. On action up, it come back to the old color. But when I press the button on the stylus after touching, it remains in the same color. Action up is not working. What can I do for solving this problem? Can I block stylus button?

Thanks